# Iterate over unlimited nested json structure

Tags: javascript, json, nested

Hi I have a JSON which is nested and can also have unlimited hierarchy. Below is the structure of JSON -

```
[{
    "name": "Main",
    "leaf": false,
    "id": 12,
    "ParentId": null,
    "children": [{
        "name": "Sub Main 1",
        "leaf": false,
        "id": 13,
        "ParentId": 12,
        "children": [{
            "name": "child 1",
            "id": 15,
            "ParentId": 13,
            "leaf": true
        }, {
            "name": "child 2",
            "id": 16,
            "ParentId": 13,
            "leaf": true
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Sub Main 2",
        "leaf": false,
        "id": 14,
        "ParentId": 12,
        "children": [{
            "name": "child 1",
            "id": 17,
            "ParentId": 14,
            "leaf": true
        }, {
            "name": "child 2",
            "id": 18,
            "ParentId": 14,
            "leaf": true
        }]
    }]
}]
```

and I want the output to be as -

```
[
    [{
        "name": "Main",
        "leaf": false,
        "id": 12,
        "ParentId": null,
    }, {
        "name": "Sub Main 1",
        "leaf": false,
        "id": 13,
        "ParentId": 12
    }, {
        "name": "child 1",
        "id": 15,
        "ParentId": 13,
        "leaf": true
    }],
    [{
        "name": "Main",
        "leaf": false,
        "id": 12,
        "ParentId": null,
    }, {
        "name": "Sub Main 1",
        "leaf": false,
        "id": 13,
        "ParentId": 12
    }, {
        "name": "child 2",
        "id": 16,
        "ParentId": 13,
        "leaf": true
    }],
    [{
        "name": "Main",
        "leaf": false,
        "id": 12,
        "ParentId": null,
    }, {
        "name": "Sub Main 2",
        "leaf": false,
        "id": 13,
        "ParentId": 12
    }, {
        "name": "child 1",
        "id": 15,
        "ParentId": 13,
        "leaf": true
    }],
    [{
        "name": "Main",
        "leaf": false,
        "id": 12,
        "ParentId": null,
    }, {
        "name": "Sub Main 2",
        "leaf": false,
        "id": 13,
        "ParentId": 12
    }, {
        "name": "child 1",
        "id": 15,
        "ParentId": 13,
        "leaf": true
    }]
]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Use recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the path to the leafes and push the path then to the result set.

```js
function getValues(array) {
    var result = [];

    array.forEach(function iter(path) {
        return function (o) {
            var temp = path.concat({ name: o.name, leaf: o.leaf, id: o.id, ParentId: o.ParentId });
            if (o.children) {
                o.children.forEach(iter(temp));
                return;
            }
            result.push(temp);
        };
    }([]));

    return result;
}

var data = [{ name: "Main", leaf: false, id: 12, ParentId: null, children: [{ name: "Sub Main 1", leaf: false, id: 13, ParentId: 12, children: [{ name: "child 1", id: 15, ParentId: 13, leaf: true }, { name: "child 2", id: 16, ParentId: 13, leaf: true }] }, { name: "Sub Main 2", leaf: false, id: 14, ParentId: 12, children: [{ name: "child 1", id: 17, ParentId: 14, leaf: true }, { name: "child 2", id: 18, ParentId: 14, leaf: true }] }] }],
    result = getValues(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But when I am trying with my JSON it is giving me eight array items with three items in each. I don't know what is missing in my JSON. But with your variable data it is working fine.

Comment: I am using this structure - [{"name": "Main","leaf": false,"id": 1000,"ParentId": null,"teams":[{"name": "Sub Main 1","leaf": false,"id": 1100,"ParentId": 1000,"teams":[{"name": "child 1","id": 1110,"ParentId": 1100,"leaf": true}, {"name": "child 2","id": 2110,"ParentId": 1100,"leaf": true}]}, {"name": "Sub Main 2","leaf": false,"id": 2100,"ParentId": 1000,"teams":[{"name": "child 1","id": 3100,"ParentId": 2100,"leaf": true}, {"name": "child 2","id": 4100,"ParentId": 2100,"leaf": true}]}]}]

Comment: Thanks Nina, your solution works like charm...!!! There was problem in my code but I fixed it and worked. Thanks again...